# Invariant direction of a non-compact subset of $SL(2,\mathbb{R})$.

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, geometry, lie-groups

I want to prove the following statement:

> PROPOSITION: Let $G$ be a closed subgroup of $SL(2,\mathbb{R})$.
>   Suppose that G is non compact. Then the following are equal:
>
> (i) There is no finite set $L\subset\mathbb{P}^1$ such that $M(L)=L$ for all $M\in G$.
>
> (ii) There is no finite set $L\subset\mathbb{P}^1$ with $|L|=1$ or $2$ ($|L|$ is the cardinality of the set $L$), such that $M(L)=L$ for all $M\in G$.

Trivially (i) implies (ii).

For the converse I'm just able to prove the following result:

> LEMMA: If $M\in SL(2,\mathbb{R})$ has 3 different invariant direction then $M=\pm \mathbb{I}$

Indeed if $M= \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
a & b \\
c & d \end{array} \right)$ and 
$\bar g=\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
g\\
1\end{array} \right)\in\mathbb{P}^1$  then:

$$\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
a & b \\
c & d \end{array} \right)\bar g=\bar g \iff \frac{ag+b}{cg+d}=g \iff cg^2+(-a+d)g-b=0$$

So we have proved the lemma.

I need to prove the following lemma to conlude the proof of the proposition:

> LEMMA: If there exists a finite set $L\subset\mathbb{P}^1$ with $|L|>2$ such that $M(L)=L$ for all $M\in G$ then all $M\in G$ has 3 different invariant direction.

The only think that I know is that a closed subgroup of $SL(2,\mathbb{R})$ is compact if and only if it is conjugated to a closed subgroup of $O(2,\mathbb{R})$

Any suggestion?

Comment: Hint: If $3\le |L|<\infty$ then a finite index subgroup $H< G$ will fix $L$ elementwise. What can you say about this subgroup $H$? What does it tell you about the group $G$?

Comment: What means that $H$ fix $L$ elementwise?

Comment: This means that $\forall x\in L$ $\forall h\in H$, $h(x)=x$.

Comment: If exists an $H$ that fix $L$ elementwise then $H$ is just the identity (this is my first lemma).

Comment: And so? How can I conclude?

Comment: What can you conclude about the size of the group $G$ if $H<G$ is the trivial finite index subgroup of $G$?

Comment: My problem is the following: we have proved that the trivial group is a soubgroup of $G$ but this is trivial. If we proved that every finite index subgroup $H<G$ fixes $L$ elementwise (why is this true?) than we can conclude that $G$ is infinite. But this does not implies that G is not compact... Can you give me another hint please?

Comment: If a group G contains a trivial finite index subgroup, what does it say about cardinality of G itself?

Comment: I think that I don't understand your definition of trivial finite index subgroup. Is the group that only containes the identity?

Comment: Yes, the trivial group is the one which consists of a single element.

Comment: But every group contains the trivial group as a subgroup.. so what can I conclude?

Comment: Do you know what index of a subgroup is?

Comment: I checked the definition.. but I never use it

Comment: So I can conclude that G is finite. But why H need to be a finite index subgroup?

Comment: Can you write for me the complete solution to the problem... I would like to understand the details. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $L\subset {\mathbb R}P^1$ is a finite set of cardinality $n\ge 3$ and that $G< PGL(2, {\mathbb R})$ is a subgroup preserving $L$. We thus have the restriction homomorphism $\rho: G\to Perm(L)\cong \Sigma_n$, the permutation group on $n$ elements; $\rho$ is given by restricting elements of $g$ to $L$. You already know (your 1st lemma) that the kernel of $\rho$ equals $\{1\}$; hence, $\rho: G\to \Sigma_n$ is injective, hence, $G$ has cardinality $\le n!$, hence, $G$ is compact. We conclude that a noncompact subgroup of $PGL(2, {\mathbb R})$ cannot preserve a finite subset of ${\mathbb R}P^1$ consisting of $\ge 3$ elements. Thus, (ii) $\Rightarrow$ (i) in your question. qed